# "But to be unable"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[the source](https://books.google.jo/books?id=dXewCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT11&dq=war%20and%20peace%20seemed%20but%20to%20be%20unable%20to%20diminish%20its%20effect&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi12_ab-evWAhXrI8AKHXxhACgQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=war%20and%20peace%20seemed%20but%20to%20be%20unable%20to%20diminish%20its%20effect&f=false)

> She seemed to wish, **but to be unable**, to diminish its effect.

I want to discern the meaning of the phrase "but to be unable" in this text.

Does it mean she wish, but she hadn't had the ability?

Or could we put in another way like: ...wish, but unable, to diminish ...?

Comment: _but = only_ here, i.e. _only to be unable_

Comment: Thank u. Now it makes sense. I consulted the dictionary, but didn't find any answer implying it means "only. @MvLog

Comment: I don't really think it specifically means "only" here.  You can still read it as being "but", like:  She seemed to wish to diminish its effect, but to be unable to diminish its effect.

Comment: @stangdon Your variant lacks brevity and the air of bad luck: _I ran to the station only to find that I had missed the train_. It might be put as: _I ran to the station, but found that I had missed the train,_ but that would be just a description of the sequence of events.

Comment: I think that the author was just trying to avoid using "seemed" twice. "She seemed to wish, but (seemed) to be unable, to diminish its effect." But I don't think it reads well nor is easy to understand.

Comment: @user3169 It's from **_War and Peace_** : _Helene was so lovely that not only did she not show any trace of coquetry, but on the contrary she even appeared shy of her unquestionable and all too victorious beauty. **She seemed to wish, but to be unable, to diminish its effect.**
"How lovely!" said everyone who saw her; and the vicomte lifted his shoulders and dropped his eyes as if startled by something extraordinary when she took her seat opposite and beamed upon him also with her unchanging smile._

Comment: I absolutely disagree with MvLog's comment. It does not mean "only", it is the ordinary meaning of "but"  = "and conversely".

Comment: @MvLog - I know it lacks brevity; I would never say it that way in real life, but I was trying to be unambiguous about it.

Answer (score 3):

+1 to Colin for his answer.  This is just an attempt (probably futile)  to clarify.

*She seemed to wish*...  requires a complement.  The complement is the infinitival *to diminish its effect*.

> She seemed to wish ... to diminish its effect.

The (IMO awkward) "but to be unable" is governed by **seemed**.

She seemed ... to be unable.

**unable** requires  a complement. Its complement is "to diminish its effect".

> She seemed to wish to diminish its effect but [she seemed to be] unable to do so.

Cascading or nested complements:

```
She seemed
   to wish
      to diminish its effect
but
   [seemed] to be unable
      to [diminish its effect]
```

Comment: Thank you. As I know, seems is a linking verb; means it could be followed by an adjective. So why the translator put "to be" before it? "But [seemed] unable to diminish its effect" without including "to be".

Comment: @Bavyan Yaldo: **SEEM** can be complemented by an infinitival as well, and in this sentence it has already been so complemented; it is most likely for the sake of parallelism and congruency that that we find the translator using two infinitivals rather than first an infinitival and then an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

> She seemed to wish, but to be unable, to diminish its effect.

means

> She seemed to wish to diminish its effect, but she seemed to be unable to do so.

Comment: = She seemed to wish to diminish its effect, only to be unable to do so.

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean. I suspect that "only" is even less clear than "but" in that context: the problem is the syntax, not the words.

Comment: But I have to admit that in the original there is no such an air of contrast: _Она как будто желала и не могла умалить действие своей красоты._ Literally: _She seemed (= as if) to wish **and** be unable to diminish the effect of her beauty._